# C++ overloaded typecast operator ignored

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I am having the strangest issue while trying to use create an overloaded typecast operator.
As a test, I have added the following operator into my Vector2 math class:

```
operator Vector2 <T> () const {return (Vector2 <T> (100, 100));};
```

And I am using the following code to test the operator:

```
Vector2 <float> vec01 (1, 1);
Vector2 <float> vec02 (static_cast <Vector2 <float>> (vec01));

std::cout << vec02 << '\n';
```

First, the code is setting vec01 to the value (1, 1), which works fine.

Next, I am creating another vector, and doing a static cast in its constructor (which in turn should call the typecast overload).

However, when I print out the value of vec2, it prints the value (1, 1), instead of the value specified in the overload.

After stepping through the code, I have confirmed that it is in fact never being called.

Does anyone know why? I have been looking for a solution for the past few hours, but with no luck.
If it helps, I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

**Edit:** I should also note that the Vector2 class is templated.

Comment: You're trying to overload a typecast from a type to itself?

Comment: As a test, yes. I have also modified the code to work with my Vector3 and Vector4 classes, but I get the same result.

Comment: Show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can compile, run, and produce your reported output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the object that you are trying to convert has the same type as the result, [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) is performed. This ends up invoking the appropriate constructor. If `Vector2` has a move constructor, that is what will be invoked to perform the `static_cast`. If not, the copy constructor will be invoked.

Comment: I have also modified the code to work with my Vector3 and Vector4 classes, but I get the same result.

Comment: You were right. It was in fact the various constructors that were being called.